# HTML Email Campaigns - Layering text over image?

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have a client that would like the attached to be built (I've blocked some information out so it doesn't look great).

Basically, they would like the two circles area's "New for 2016" and "From £11.59*" to be text. I know with HTML emails the text can't be on an angle but can anyone else see any other problems as to why this won't work for HTML email build?

[Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlZhJ.png)

Comment: It may make sense to do this on web sites for SEO and other reaons. But why go through this pain in an E-Mail, where loads of things can go wrong with positioning, the background image not loading, etc.?  I'd just put it in the image and call it a day. Everything else seems like a waste of time & money.

Comment: You could always leave that text as part of the image, exact positioning an nice graphics are difficult to get consistent across email clients. As long as the majority of important text is actual text, you wont hit any spam filters or major problems.

Comment: @Pekka웃 They want to send this as an email campaign.

Comment: @DBS They want those specific parts to be text as, they would like to change depending on the client. 

I'm not so much concerned with spam problems I'm more asking along the lines of design issues. Say we made the text straight can you still have this as text in those circle or would this cause a whole load of coding issues?

Comment: This is problematic in an E-Mail due to the technical problems mentioned above. You can generate images with the correct text on server side

Comment: @Pekka웃 to answer your question, "But why go through this pain in an E-Mail", it's because often the prices are dynamically generated by ESP and while it's possible to "bake" the price into an image, it's often too tedious and image generating is done on 3rd party providers what introduces additional obstacle to get it into an ESP territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a number of elements that are graphical and difficult to represent in an email.

The circles and the angled text, as you correctly pointed out are two of them.

Also, if you'd include images most clients normally don't immediately load them but require user confirmation, making it look very ugly at first (this is the argument that always catches with marketing).

Thirdly, was designed as a text medium and most HTML is often included (warning, opinion following) just due to people being to lazy to think about a good text email which is usually the better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What problem do the circles poses? Cause say if we made the text straight would we also have problems getting the text in those circles?

Comment: The problem with the circle is that in plain HTML, there is no possibility to add a circle. You could however use CSS to add them, David Walsh has a nice [tutorial](https://davidwalsh.name/css-circles) on that.

But to be honest, as someone who does web development, I shudder thinking about inline CSS.

Comment: I would recommend to use a square image of a circle and add your text ontop of that. This wont work if you got a colorful, moving background, but when it's plain, that would work. I often work with Clients from the Print industry and they are often ok with it being a Image of the Circle and text for it to be displayed correcty. Also most Email receiver load Images from the getgo and almost none block them. Well that's only my expirience.

Comment: I agree, the design is poor imho. Those roundels come from print-oriented designer, but that's not the best way to get the message to the customer. The current trends are lean, minimalistic, flat designs. This design looks from previous generations. That's my humble opinion.

Comment: @revelt you don't know the customer base the E-Mail is addressing though. Not every audience is into lean/minimalistic/flat

Answer (score 0):

You can layer text or foreground images over a background image. [backgrounds.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/) is the best tool to do this. Here is an example:

```
<td background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="120" height="92" valign="top">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:120px;height:92px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
    <![endif]-->
        <div>
        <!-- Your content goes here -->
            <img src="">
            <br>
            Text Text Text
            <table> more layouts </table>
        </div>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
</td>
```

You'll have to be creative to achieve the design linked above, but in principle you should be able to achieve this (or something close to this) in most email clients.